# Alternating cards and cycles

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have 5 cards labeled from 1-5. We deal them out in order:

1 2 3 4 5

Now we do the following shuffle. We take the top card (1), put it on the bottom, deal the second card (2), then put the next top card (3) on the bottom, then deal (4), then put (5) at the bottom, then deal (1), and then (5) and finally (3). Every turn is top card at the bottom of the deck, deal the next card, top card bottom, etc. until you have only one card left which you deal.

2 4 1 5 3

We keep doing this until we get the original 1 2 3 4 5 configuration. This takes 5 turns.

How do you solve this for $N$ cards?

Approach: If we can do this for 1 round of shuffling we can get the length of every cycle. The complete cycle would be the LCM of that. So we need the LCM of a set of numbers that sums up to the number of cards...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you are looking for is $a(n)$ in [A051732](http://oeis.org/A051732).  OEIS doesn't provide a closed form for $a(n)$, and looking at some of its values, a closed form might be fairly difficult.

Be careful reading the table they provide, because I think that they begin counting from $0$ cards.  With this in mind, tt seems that $a(57)=13,300$, whereas $a(64)=7$.

Interesting questions to ask would be:

1. Does $a(n)$ approach infinity?  If not, is it at least unbounded?
2. Is $a(n)$ surjective onto the natural numbers?  If so, does it hit every natural number infinitely many times?
3. Can we give a closed form for $a(f(n))$ for a suitably chosen function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$.

I haven't given any of these questions thought, but they might be interesting to answer before trying to find a closed form.

It seems that $a(2^n)=n+1$, and if true, this would show that $a(n)$ is surjective and unbounded.  The proof shouldn't be too hard.